# c# - limit certain characters inside textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, text, count, character

I am trying to limit the amount of a certain character (in my case a comma (,)) inside my textbox. I want it to only allow max 9 commas in the textbox. If the user attempts to add more commas than 9, it should display a messagebox with the error, and then also not allow the user to enter more into the textbox.

In my application, I allow the user to add 10 tags to a textbox separated by commas.

An example input by the user could look like this: `summer,sexy,hot,beautiful,girls,guys,food,music,funny,lol`

That is the max limit of tags allowed in the textbox (9 commas).
And when they reach that limit, it should block them from typing any more commas. I hope I was clear enough.

Here is my code so far. My textbox is called tagBox.

```
private void tagBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Allow max 10 tags in the tag box
            string tags = tagBox.Text;
            int count = tags.Split(',').Length - 1;
            if (count > 9)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Max 10 tags are allowed.", "Notice", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
        }
```

I only managed to make the messagebox appear. But how do I stop them from typing in more commas?

Comment: use KeyPress event or KeyUp event instead of TextChanged event. then in the KeyPress/KeyUp event if the current comma count is already 9 and the current character being press is a comma you can cancel the event the comma character will be forbidden.

Comment: If you create a custom control inheriting from `Textbox` you can override the keypressed handler and ignore them if your over your limit

Comment: Okay I will change it to KeyPress instead. But how do I cancel/ignore the keys? (I still want the user to be able to press DELETE and that, to remove/edit the current 10 tags). I just dont want to allow them to add more after a 9th comma.

Comment: inside the keyPress event you can detect what is the character being press from there you can set e.Handled = false; so it will be forbidden.

Comment: so the same as my code above, but before messagebox I just type e.Handled = false; ? (on KeyPress instead of TextChanged)

Comment: yes. i had posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look something like this:

```
private void tagBox_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // Allow max 10 tags in the tag box
    string tags = tagBox.Text;
    int count = tags.Split(',').Length - 1;
    if (count > 9 && e.KeyChar == ',')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Max 10 tags are allowed.", "Notice", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
    else        
        e.Handled = false;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. First I changed it to count==9 instead of count > 9, since it allowed 10 commas with your code. (Should be max 10 tags, and max 9 commas). Then the messagebox appeared at the right place. But after I clicked OK in the messagebox,I could still type in more tags and messageboxes just kept popping up. So that was almost the solution, but still not working :/

Comment: I see you changed it to e.Handled = true; at the bottom. After I did that, it did not allow me to write in anything at all

Comment: you can disable the textBox, but you should have a button enable in again.

Comment: I wouldn't like that, it would not be very userfriendly if they wanted to quickly edit a tag or remove one, etc...

Comment: I had refresh the answer, can you try again while I setup a similar code.

Comment: Works perfectly now with your latest code! Just change count > 9 to count == 9. Thanks a lot! :D If it is count==9, it means "if the count of commas is 9 (max amount), then stop), and not if it is larger than 9 (which means it already exceeded limit)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something like this

```
    Public class TagTextBox : TextBox
    {
        Public override OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs args)
        {
            // Do logic here
            // Call this to accept Key
            base.OnKeyDown(sender, args);
         }
    }
```